# NGRX Store fires multiple events on dispatch

Tags: observable, ngrx

I have an app, which has a firestore in background and an ngrx store for the application data.

I want the store to handle my application data and I want the firestore to provide me observables from my database. In my case a user makes a selection, so it is applicationData for me and is dispatched to the store.

According to the selection that is now in my ngrx store, I want to get an Observable from my firestore. when the selection changes, I want to ask the firestore again for a new Observable. My approach is the following:

my ngOnInit()

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedGroupUid$ = this.store.select(fromApp.advGetSelectedGroupId);
    
    this.selectedGroup$ = this.selectedGroupUid$.pipe(
      switchMap(gUid => this.groupService.readGroup(gUid))
    );
```

The Event is fired as the result of a Modal dialog

```js
  onSelectionModal() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(StartAdventureModalComponent);
    this.modalRef.result.then((data) => {
      this.store.dispatch(GroupActions.selectStartWithGroup(data))
    });
  }
```

My Problem is, that I dispatch the value once, the store is called once, but the Observable selectedGroupUid$ is fired ~35 times. Meaning I read ~35 times from my database but I only need to read it exactly once on change.

I tried it by debouncing, but this only waits some time and then it executes all ~35 calls to my database.

I do not want to handle this with a subscription, if I can prevent it. When I am searching in the internet I do get a load of answers, but all are not related to my problem of reducing multiple fired results to the last one without subcsribing.

Answer (score 0):

Does the selector also get fired that many times?
I think you could use `distinctUntilChanged` operator to reduce the amount of db calls.

```
   this.selectedGroup$ = this.selectedGroupUid$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(gUid => this.groupService.readGroup(gUid))
    );
```